# serve a single image with sinatra no matter whats asked for

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm serving an image with sinatra, but when you go the image, I want sinatra to serve up another image. So every image that is asked for on the server, will return a static image.

```
%w[sintra].each{|gem| require gem}

# <img src="https://www.mywebsite.com/1234.png">
# <img src="https://www.mywebsite.com/abcd.png">

get '/:image' do 
 image = params[:image].split(".")[0]
 # image = 1234

 if image == key 
  #do stuff
 else
  #do other stuff
 end

 #this is where I'm having a problem
 special_code_that_replaces_1234.png = "static_image_on_server.png"
 #so sinatra should return "static_image_on_server.png" no matter what image is asked for. 

end
```

I've looked through the documentation for sinatra. This specifically. 
http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object
I may be looking at the wrong part, "Triggering Another Route"
I think I'm running in circles.

My app does have a "public" directory with "static_image_on_server.png"

Comment: Does switching the path to `get '/*.*'` work better for this? You might want to ensure all your images are in `/images` to make this mapping more specific.

Comment: The way the data comes in is arbitrary. I cannot inject another image in its place. Or I dont understand how someone could.

Comment: Ah, if you have no control over the incoming route then you'll need a blanket route.

Comment: Of course there will be a validation in the future. I haven't thought of that. Sounds a little hacky. I'm using ProxyPass in my apache config to allow multiple sinatra apps. Can you post a link of an example/documentation of your comment above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes you have a directory `public/imgs` where you store your images:

### With redirect():

```
require 'sinatra'

get "/imgs/*.*" do
  img_name, ext = params[:splat]

  if image_name == key 
    #do stuff
  else
    #do other stuff
  end

  redirect to('/imgs/alien1.png')
end
```

By default, Sinatra will first check if the requested file is in the ./public folder and return it if it exists. If the file isn't in ./public, then Sinatra will try to match a route. So the code in a route cannot prevent a user from seeing existing images in your public folder.

You *can* add `disable :static` to the top of your routes file to stop Sinatra from looking in ./public for the requested file. Instead, Sinatra will go straight to route matching.  In that case, the redirect() in the example WILL cause an infinite loop.  So if you have images in the public folder that you don't want users to see, you can't use redirect().

### With send_file():

It looks like tadman's send_file() solution requires an absolute(or relative) file system path, so you can do this:

```
require 'sinatra'

get "/imgs/*.*" do
  img_name, ext = params[:splat]

  if image_name == key 
    #do stuff
  else
    #do other stuff
  end

  send_file File.expand_path('imgs/alien1.png', settings.public_folder)
end
```

Note that with send_file(), the original url, with the originally requested image, will remain displayed in the browser, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: That was it. I just need to redirect. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2446058, Hmmm...now that I posted that, I wonder why it doesn't cause an infinite loop?

Comment: @user2446058, It looks like send_file() requires an absolute file system path, so I added an example of how to get send_file() to work.

Comment: @user2446058, By default Sinatra will first check if the requested file is in the ./public folder and return it if it exists. If the file isn't in ./public, then Sinatra will try to match a route. If I add `disable :static` to the top of the file, then Sinatra will NOT look in ./public for files and instead Sinatra will go straight to route matching. In that case, my solution WILL cause an infinite loop. So if you have images in the public folder that you don't want users to see, you can't use redirect().

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is handled like this:

```
get '/*.*' do
 # ... Your code ...

 # Send static file.
 send_file 'static_image_on_server.png'
end
```

Comment: I created a new route matching your code above and im getting a 404 error for the original image that was asked for. I also commented out my code.

Comment: Is there anything in your Sinatra log?